# Get Photo of the object in widget - SocialEngine Widget

Tags: php, widget, socialengine

I am beginner in SocialEngine and I want to know if there is any way to get the photo of the object in the widget. 
Like i know we can get the photo of the object in view using following code.

//in controller

```
$table  = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable("mytable","module");
$select = $table->select()->where->("table_id", 1);
$fetch  = $table->fetchRow($select);
$this->view->fetch = $fetch;
```

//in view

```
echo $this->itemPhoto($this->fetch, "thumb.normal");
```

above line would product the image if there is any otherwise will load the default image.

But this line of code is not working in widget. 
I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that first param you're passing to `$this->itemPhoto` is a `User` instance:
`$this->itemPhoto($user, 'thumb.normal', $user->getTitle())`

Seems that in your case $this->fetch is simply a `Row`. You can create user using this code: `Engine_Api::_()->getItem('user', $user_id);`. Hope this helps.